# VU meter: datalabel does not show in its position

Tags: highcharts, gauge

I am using [highchart](http://highcharts.com) to display vu meter with data-label. Chart display and work correctly with live data from database but i have problem to show data-label in correct position.
I have tried `crop` and `overflow` options as it said [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.overflow) but it didn't work for me.
[image]
Here is the code i captured from debuger:

```
<g class="highcharts-data-labels" visibility="visible" zIndex="2" transform="translate(10,40) scale(1 1)">
  <g zIndex="1" style="cursor:default;" transform="translate(0,-999)">
    <rect rx="3" ry="3" fill="url(#highcharts-3)" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="55" height="21" stroke="silver" stroke-width="1"></rect>
    <text x="3" y="15" style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color:#666;line-height:14px;fill:#666;" zIndex="1">
       <tspan style="fill:#339" x="3">0.96 ^H</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
</g>
```

Then when i manually change `-999` to `0` in the second line data-label shows as below:

`<g zIndex="1" style="cursor:default;"`**`transform="translate(0,0)"`**`>`

[image]

However when the next live data arrives, it will changes to `transform="translate(0, -999)"`.
Is there any way to fix offset for data label?
I'll also appreciate any other solution.

Comment: Recreate issue on jsFiddle, please. Also make sure you have latest version of Highcharts (3.0.8). [Here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/search?q=gauge+datalabel&ref=cmdform&type=Issues) is a list of bugs with gauge dataLabel position.

Comment: @PawełFus i create the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/G5UUn/ and it works nice. so my problem was using Highcharts version 3.0.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Pawel Fus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1451635/pawel-fus) said the problem solved by using latest version of Highcharts from [here](http://www.highcharts.com/download)